# switch off sound effects, when headphones are connected to phone

Tags: audio, samsung-galaxy-s-plus

When I use headphones, music is only in headphones, but info sound(ie when I get  email our IM message) is playing to phone dynamics. How to change this behaviour?

Phone is Galaxy S plus.